# Get variables with PHP in a Turbo Pascal way

Tags: php, variables, get, pascal, turbo-pascal

In Turbo Pascal we have the `read();` function. Is there a function to get variables, sent to any script on [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP)?

Comment: Turbo Pascal programs and PHP scripts are typically run in totally different environments. There's no direct analogue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Turbo Pascal read() and readln() functions read from file. If no filename is specified, they read from standard input.

In PHP, you have to open the file first, then read from the file handle allocated on open: the equivalent of standard input in PHP is php://input, so something like:

```
$filename = "php://input";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, 1024);
fclose($handle);
```

But note that it's not particularly practical to do this from a web interface, only from the CLI

Comment: and how to get data from that input?

Comment: read() in turbo Pascal can read _typed_ data. So if the file is textual, and you read an integer typed variable, it will read till the first non digit, and convert from string to integer. (with IOResult variable that can be tested for errors)

Answer (score 2):

Are you maybe looking for the eval() function? http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: I think he is looking for a way to parse an incoming stream (textual?) into various variables (with possibly different typing). More or less Fscanf like functionality.